# implementing a address bar inside my site

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to have an address bar or url bar inside my site with basic functions like back, forward, refresh, stop. maybe more complicated but also have a way to store history. i've been searching all over.

thanks to all for helping

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Loaded in frames? Iframes? Webmonkey had tutorials on how to do this back in 2003.

Comment: browser is supposed to do that ...

Comment: A browser within a browser... "We need to go deeper!"

Comment: For all those clever folk who say, "But *why*???", consider http://www.bitty.com/ The *application* is not always obvious, but should not be up to consensus. This is entirely and easily answered.

Comment: http://lithify.me/ (enable javascript) has a shell-bar on top. you can enter commands there (instead of clicking), maybe that gives you an idea about how to do what you want to have.

Comment: Fun thing to do in Firefox: Type this into the address bar: `chrome://browser/content/browser.xul`

Comment: Next... A Browser inside a browser inside another! thats deep! Thanks for the comments guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I love the Quasdunk's comment hence the plus point :) And even looking at the bitty I do not see much reason to implement it but hey maybe its for something amazing we can't perceive.

Anyhow here is how you should roughly go about implementing this:

```
$(function () {

        window.myBrowser = {
            'addressBar': $('#addressBar'),
            'browserWindow': $('#browserWindow'),
            'backBtn': $('#backBtn'),
            'forwardBtn': $('#forwardBtn'),
            'goBtn': $('#goBtn')
        };

        myBrowser.goBtn.click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var address = myBrowser.addressBar.val();

            if (address && address.indexOf('http://') > -1) {
                myBrowser.browserWindow.attr('src', myBrowser.addressBar.val());
            }
            else if (address) {
                myBrowser.browserWindow.attr('src', 'http://' + myBrowser.addressBar.val());
            }
            // maybe play a little more to get the www and the rest into account
            // don't want to do the whole thing for you :)
        });

        myBrowser.backBtn.click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            browserWindowFrame.history.back();
        });
        myBrowser.forwardBtn.click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            browserWindowFrame.history.forward();
        });

    });
```

The body is this:

```
<a href='#' id='backBtn'>back</a>
<a href='#' id='forwardBtn'>forward</a>
<input type="text" id='addressBar' />
<a href='#' id='goBtn'>Go</a>
<iframe id='browserWindow' src='' name='browserWindowFrame'></iframe>
```

Comment: Well what if you wanted to have it at the bottom as well as at the top, minimizing mouse movement.  What if you open a modeless window and wanted your own custom interface displayed? What if you wanted to position navigation controls somewhere in-page, again to minimize mouse movement? --- all of these reasons seem like good ideas to me :)

Comment: Yes maybe. I just remembered the site that you can shoot, rip, throw ink etc on any website you want. it was really fun to do at my last job :)))

Comment: Great now to make it more funtional. Turn it into a bar and play with the iframe. Just wondering how do have better control of browserwindowframe. thanks XGreen.

Comment: what sort of control are you talking about?

Comment: For example implementing the browser window here [link](http://jsbin.com/uruto4/) where it says (tab 1) taking up the entire gray area under the tab. Thanks again @Xgreen for your interest in my experiment.

Comment: Obviously in order to create the tabbing features one iframe would not be sufficient. You will need to append a new iframe window for each tab being created. so each tab can have its own history object and src

Comment: Thanks. Now i have something to play with for a couple of days. im trying to learn JavaScript and PHP but i believe that the best way to learn is working on a project.